# Access VBA: Update Reference Library with AutoExec macro, work's in accdb format but not when compiled?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Here is my VBA code to be executed in MS Access 2010. For simplicity I've removed error handling in this code. Function resides in a module with a different name.

```
Public Function ReAddLibrary()

Dim accessProj As Access.Application 
Dim chkRef As Access.Reference ' 
Set accessProj = Access.Application

   ' Check through the selected references.
   For Each chkRef In accessProj.References
      ' If the reference "MyReference" exists then remove.
      If chkRef.Name = "MyReference" Then
         accessProj.References.Remove chkRef
         Exit For
      End If

   Next

‘ Add back the reference “MyReference” from specified location.   
accessProj.References.AddFromFile "Access Database Path"

End Function
```

Adapted from
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221567(v=office.11).aspx

---

**Premise**
Users, use Access databases as the front end, naturally there’s an array of them. One thing in common is that they share reference to an accde database which houses shared functions. Naturally these databases are compiled to stop users getting at the VBA/Design mode. The database that is being referenced is also compiled. Currently work is being done to its accdb equivalent and every time it is published as an accde to the database location, an unresolved reference is created. The reference path hasn’t changed location (Nor will it).  All recipient Accdb databases work fine, but their equivalent compiled versions throw a generic error when a button linked-subroutine is clicked for example.

If I use the above code as a subroutine linked to an on click event such as “On Load” for a form housing a button in question, this code works perfectly, even compiled. But if I convert this to a function and link it to a macro named “`AutoExec`,” it will execute the macro when opening the database but will.

- Work in a non-compiled database
- Will not work when database is compiled

The AutoExec macro route is because I just want this code pasted in once and executed once when the user opens the database, so the reference is recreated and not broken.

---

**Macro**

```
Action: RunCode  
Function Name: ReAddLibrary ()
```

---

**My thoughts**

Initially, I’ve looked into late binding as a solution but I’m finding it hard to grasp as I don’t really code in VBA, I primarily code in sql and thus miss Intellisense and syntax highlighting. All examples are for excel workbooks making it difficult to relate. All my users and myself use the same Access 2010 so there is no version confliction. So I don’t know if this is the answer.

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/latebinding.htm

I considered running a script to recompile all the user’s databases. But, work to the referenced database is incrementally on going and booting people off would be a nuisance.

- Why, when the compiled version still retains the correct accde file
  path does it not work, when simply the referenced database has been
  recompiled again?
- Is it programmatically possible to drop a reference (If it exists)
  and add a reference, when a compiled version of Access boots up, such
  as linking it to a macro named AutoExec?
- Is there an alternative way to run the above code without having to
  add it to an ‘Event’ for all form objects? Saving me time as I can
  centralize the code in one place.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Although I am just starting to tinker with your question and will keep looking, it would be helpful to know if it is always the same reference that goes missing. What happens if you take the source to another workstation and compile it? Or make the accde on that machine. Does it work then? Possibly there is a 'trust issue'? Check this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28328054/Access-2010-Runtime-AutoExec-Macro-Function-call-problem.html Maybe an issue with doing 'certain things' in the AutoExec, but don't know. Test by open form with that code and not AutoExec.

Comment: We've checked the Trust settings and they're good. Another developer has compiled the referenced database on his machine and it still breaks the look up from the accde user end database. To add, the reference is not missing, the accdb version of end user database finds it just fine. I guess that when the source reference database is compiled again, the end user compiled database must have some mis-matching internal reference, like an Id or date time reference.

Comment: I did the test (working in the end user database to save confusion) and added the above code into an 'open form event' with some vba msgboxs for testing. Interestingly, the code works but then I realized my routine removes the reference and then adds it back. So when I compile it in the vba window it works, but, If I manually remove the reference in GUI first, then compile it, it error's as references to Functions and subroutines technically don't exist when it's compiled. This is where late binding would work in my opinion. Thanks @wayne G. Dunn That's half the confusion sorted.

Comment: A fairly decent article on early/late binding is: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115   Do you have any type of Version Control to keep each user's copy up to date whenever you roll out a change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple and sad answer is that whenever your code and/or a reference is changed, the project has to be compiled.

So, when done, you have to distribute both the project accde file and its external files (those that are updated, in practice all) to the users.

Comment: So in fact it's really easiest just to deploy the front-end files as complete "stand-alone" .accd? files with no external VBA code dependencies. If deployment is done using an automatic front-end updater then it's dead simple.

Comment: @Gustav Sorry but why? If I have a function heavy database that I recompile into an accde format (Call it Database A). Why do all the other accde databases (Databases B-Z) that reference Database A, lose the reference, when file path is the same and all Sub/Function remain unaltered. Their (B-Z) .accdb counter parts pick up the reference automatically no matter how many times I recompile Database A.  But, you are right, recompiling all B-Z databases fixes this. It's just annoying to do so, especially if Database A is going to have some on going work to it.

Comment: Yes why? Ask MS. Most likely this behaviour will never be changed, so we just have to obey and live with it.

Comment: There is only one database. Front-ends all need to match the database. If you allow different front ends they will become desynced from the back-end when the back-end is updated. Everyone needs to run the same version.